# message passing between 2 verticles under 2 different Vertx instances. Is it possible?

Tags: vert.x, vertx-verticle, vertx-eventbus

I'm trying to make communication possible between 2 verticles (X, Y) deployed using 2 different Vert.x instances.

X sends a message on *"Address"* `eventbus().send("Address", message, replyHandler)`

Is it possible for Y to listen on same address? `eventbus().localConsumer("Address", eventHandler)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `EventBus` is tied to a particular `Vertx` instance. So unless your two `Vertx` instances are part of the same [cluster](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#_creating_a_clustered_vert_x_object), there is no connection between their respective Event Buses.

You could use an event bus bridge of some-kind (like [this one](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-tcp-eventbus-bridge/java/)) to make it look like you're directly communicating between them, though you may be better off just directly using some other protocol.